# Different results from querying Facebook link_stat using http and https

Tags: facebook

I am trying to query the number of likes and shares for a particular URL. The site serves pages in both HTTP and HTTPS.

However, I noticed that HTTP and HTTPS are tracked differently. Using the following query shows the behaviour.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20like_count,share_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN%20%28%22www.oyezdigital.com/dwmoment/Gallery/Photo/10%22,%22https://www.oyezdigital.com/dwmoment/Gallery/Photo/10%22%29

Output:

```
<fql_query_response list="true">
    <link_stat>
        <like_count>0</like_count>
        <share_count>0</share_count>
    </link_stat>
    <link_stat>
        <like_count>1</like_count>
        <share_count>1</share_count>
    </link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

The link liked was the HTTPS version.

How do I get a consolidated like and share count? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that you just combine the results when you are displaying the likes and share_count in your app.